# ngIf only for _this_ element, show childs anyway

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I know the phrasing of my question might be a little weird, but here is what I want:

I have a div, that I want to wrap around an `input`, but only when `divIsNeeded`. I **always** want to show the `input` field.

going through the documentation, I couldn't find anything. Is there any way to do it?

```html
<!-- this should only be there if I actually need it, otherwise I don't want this div -->
<div *ngIf="needsInputGroup" class="input-group">
  <!-- this should always be visible -->
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="needsInputGroup" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla" />
</div>
<input *ngIf="!needsInputGroup" type="text" placeholder="bla" />
```

You can create a custom component that does that for you and reuse it everywhere. I don't think there is another way. But a custom component adds another element around the content

Comment: Yeah, that's what i do not want to use, because when I change the input slightly, I always have to edit both.

Comment: You can create a custom component that does that for you and reuse it everywhere. I don't think there is another way. But a custom component adds another element around the content.

Comment: There is another way, but it is messy. If you wrap both the opening and closing of the `<div>`'s with an `<ng-container *ngIf="needsInputGroup"></ng-container>` it will work... It might actually be better if you wanted to nest a whole lot of conditional HTML.

Comment: This results in invalid HTML which Angular won't parse.

Answer (score 0):

What Günter suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629919/2131286) works, but you have to specify the children twice. Instead, you can take leverage of `<ng-template>` element to specify the children only once. In this specific case it's not a problem because the element is rather simple, but what if the contents are larger?

Contents of `<ng-template>` will not be rendered where placed, but will instead be sort of like a definition of a light-weight component. Once placed somewhere, it will render, but not before. Another analogy for `ng-template` would be a function: you define it, but you won't get the result before you call it.

So anywhere in our template, we can define the inner contents. We give it a reference `#children`, which we will use later to render the template elsewhere.

```
<ng-template #children>
  <input type=text placeholder=bla>
</ng-template>
```

Now we render different things depending on the condition. We render the template by passing its reference (the name we've given it) to the structural directive `ngTemplateOutlet`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="needsInputGroup">
  <div class="input-group">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!needsInputGroup">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```